# Using filter() to filter words starting with a specific character in Python (how to use filter with 2 arguments)

Tags: python, filter

I have this function here to filter out all words from a list which start with a desired character

```
new_list = []
def filter_words(word_list, c):
    for word in word_list:
        if word.startswith(c):
            new_list.append(word)
        else:
            continue
```

```
lst = ["Hello", "Cat", "Dog", "House", "Helmet", "Horse", "Bird"]
filter_words(l,"H")
print(new_list)
```

This work fine - now I'm trying with filter() method

I tried this

`list(filter(filter_words, lst))` but I got this error: `TypeError: filter_woerter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'`

so I tried this

`list(filter(filter_words, l,'h'))` but then got another error: `TypeError: filter expected 2 arguments, got 3`

So, how do I pass the 2nd argument?

Comment: What does the documentation say should be passed as aguments?

Comment: A function and an iterable. I passed a function and a list, isn't it correct?

Comment: @Takuya2412 the function passed to `filter` needs to be a *predicate*, it should take a single argument, and return a single boolean indicating whether the argument should be kept in the output. Your `filter_words` obviously doesn't match this contract, as it takes two arguments and doesn't return anything.

Answer (score -1):

Your `filter_words` function already takes a list (well, an iterable) as argument and do the filtering by itself, so passing it to `filter()` makes no sense - `filter()` expects a function that takes one single element from the iterable and returns a boolean value (this is usually known as a "predicate function"). IOW you'd want:

```
def word_starts_with(word, letter):
    return word.startswith(letter)
```

and then you'd have to use a lambda as partial application so the letter is fixed:

```
filter(lambda word: word_starts_with("H"), yourlistofwords)
```

which FWIW is actually a convoluted way to write:

```
filter(lambda word: word.startswith("H"), yourlistofwords)
```

which is more idiomatically written with a list comprehension instead:

```
[word for word in yourlistofwords if word.startswith("h")]
```